# Yugabyte - how to set JDBC connection string

Tags: jdbc

On Yugabyte DB, could not find in any documentation how to deal with connection string (JDBC specifically) to make sure App (re)connects to any of surviving cluster nodes in case one node fails? All references I found shows single IP address what confuses me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can pass multiple nodes to the JDBC string by comma-separating multiple entries for the `host:post`. The JDBC driver should automatically reconnect.

But that said, we have just started working on a smart JDBC driver that is cluster aware here: https://github.com/yugabyte/ybjdbc